# Excel - I need to extract a pattern of numbers and letters from a string

Tags: excel

I have a long string of text that contains somewhere in the string a either one or two numbers followed by from 1 to 3 letters.  I need to extract the number(s) and letter(s) together into a separate cell.  In case there are multiple instances of this pattern I would like to have excel show them in the same cell separated by commas.

For example:

A1: In position 2G there was fault found. B1: 2G

or

A1: In case 32AB the top is missing. B1: 32AB

or

A1: In position 2G there was a fault found.  In case 32AB the top is missing.  B1: 2G, 32AB.

I believe I figured out the basic case here:

```
Function ExtractPos(ByVal text As String) As String

Dim result As String
Dim allMatches As Object
Dim RE As Object
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

RE.Pattern = "(\d{1,2}\w{1,4})"
RE.Global = True
RE.IgnoreCase = True
Set allMatches = RE.Execute(text)

If allMatches.Count <> 0 Then
    result = allMatches.Item(0).SubMatches.Item(0)
End If

ExtractPos = result

End Function
```

This seems to work for returning multiple results where the delimiter is specified in the function call:

```
    Function RegexExtract(ByVal text As String, _
                      Optional seperator As String = "") As String

Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim result As String
Dim allMatches As Object
Dim RE As Object
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

RE.Pattern = "(\d{1,2}\w{1,4})"
RE.Global = True
Set allMatches = RE.Execute(text)

For i = 0 To allMatches.Count - 1
    For j = 0 To allMatches.Item(i).submatches.Count - 1
        result = result & seperator & allMatches.Item(i).submatches.Item(j)
    Next
Next

If Len(result) <> 0 Then
    result = Right(result, Len(result) - Len(seperator))
End If

RegexExtract = result

End Function
```

I'm still trying to determine how to eliminate any values that match this pattern from being returned:

```
"(\d{2}JAN|\d{2}FEB|\d{2}MAR|\d{2}APR|\d{2}MAY|\d{2}JUN|\d{2}JUL|\d{2}AUG|\d{2}SEP|\d{2}OCT|\d{2}NOV|\d{2}DEC)"
```

Comment: What type of solution are you looking for? VBA + regular expressions = very straightforward, but Excel formula only = quite difficult. In any event, what have you tried?

Comment: I was looking for a way to do it with excel formula's but gave up.  I'm open to vba but I'm very much a novice.

Comment: No one will write you a code here. So, show some effort from your end and tell us where you stuck and we'll be happy to help you.

Comment: I could use some help figuring out how to exclude a date from being returned from my input string (I found cases where the string contains DDMMM or 25JUN for example.  I figured out that I could extract this by replacing the Re.Pattern with this

`RE.Pattern = "(\d{2}JAN\d{2}FEB|\d{2}MAR|\d{2}APR|\d{2}MAY|\d{2}JUN|\d{2}JUL|\d{2}AUG\d{2}SEP|\d{2}OCT|\d{2}NOV|\d{2}DEC|)"`

but now I'm unsure how I could have all date values excluded from the output?

Comment: @woodboaero  "(\d{2}(JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC))"  simplified form